# Rolle's Theorem to Prove $f^{(n)}$ has a zero in interval

Tags: numerical-methods

(Use Rolle's Theorem) Let $f\in C^n[\alpha, \beta ]$. Suppose that $f$ has a zero of multiplicity $m$ at $\alpha$ and a root of multiplicity $k$ at $\beta$, where $m \geq 1, k \geq 1$ and $m+k-1=n$. Prove that $f^{(n)}$ has at least one zero in $(\alpha, \beta)$.

Not really sure where to start with this one. 
Thank you in advance for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Well, do you know anything about roots with high multiplicity? What does it have to do with derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

Prove, as usual, that $f^{(j)}$ has $m+k-j$ roots in the interval $[α,β]$, counted with multiplicity.

As example, in the first step you get per Rolle one root of $f'$ inside $(α,β)$ and the multiplicities at $α$ and $β$ reduce to $m-1$ and $k-1$, so that the total count of roots for $f'$ is $$(m-1)+(k-1)+1=m+k-1.$$